# What is the best way to convert an array to a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hashmap

In Ruby, given an array in one of the following forms...

```
[apple, 1, banana, 2]
[[apple, 1], [banana, 2]]
```

...what is the best way to convert this into a hash in the form of...

```
{apple => 1, banana => 2}
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

**NOTE**: For a concise and efficient solution, please see [Marc-André Lafortune's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20831486/332936) below.

This answer was originally offered as an alternative to approaches using flatten, which were the most highly upvoted at the time of writing. I should have clarified that I didn't intend to present this example as a best practice or an efficient approach. Original answer follows.

---

**Warning!** Solutions using **flatten** will not preserve Array keys or values!

Building on @John Topley's popular answer, let's try:

```
a3 = [ ['apple', 1], ['banana', 2], [['orange','seedless'], 3] ]
h3 = Hash[*a3.flatten]
```

This throws an error:

```
ArgumentError: odd number of arguments for Hash
        from (irb):10:in `[]'
        from (irb):10
```

The constructor was expecting an Array of even length (e.g. ['k1','v1,'k2','v2']).  What's worse is that a different Array which flattened to an even length would just silently give us a Hash with incorrect values.

If you want to use Array keys or values, you can use **map**:

```
h3 = Hash[a3.map {|key, value| [key, value]}]
puts "h3: #{h3.inspect}"
```

This preserves the Array key:

```
h3: {["orange", "seedless"]=>3, "apple"=>1, "banana"=>2}
```

Comment: This is the same as Hash[a3], since a3 == a3.map{|k,v| [k,v]} is true, it's actually the equivalent to a3.dup.

Comment: Instead of using map, why not just specify the depth of flatten?  For example: `h3 = Hash[*a3.flatten(1)]` instead of `h3 = Hash[*a3.flatten]` which would throw an error.

Comment: This answer is not efficient. It is also out of date. See my answer.

Comment: `a3 = [ ['apple', 1], ['banana', 2], [['orange','seedless'], 3] ] h3 = Hash[*a3.flatten(1)]`

Comment: Yes, I think  Marc-André's `to_h` is better.

Comment: @Marc-André Lafortune thank you, I have updated my answer to direct users to yours.

Answer (score 153):

Simply use `Hash[*array_variable.flatten]`

For example:

```
a1 = ['apple', 1, 'banana', 2]
h1 = Hash[*a1.flatten(1)]
puts "h1: #{h1.inspect}"

a2 = [['apple', 1], ['banana', 2]]
h2 = Hash[*a2.flatten(1)]
puts "h2: #{h2.inspect}"
```

Using `Array#flatten(1)` limits the recursion so `Array` keys and values work as expected.

Comment: Oh, the eloquence! This is why I love Ruby

Comment: WARNING: answers using flatten will cause problems if you want Array keys or values.

Comment: I've posted an alternative solution below that will avoid problems with Array keys or values.

Comment: It's better to not try and do a catch-all solution for this. If your keys and values are paired as in [[key1,value1],[key2,value2]] then just pass it to Hash[] without fattening. Hash[a2] == Hash[*a2.flatten]. If the array is already flattened as in, [key1, value1, key2, value2] then just prefix the var with *, Hash[*a1]

Comment: How! How! How!... How did you come up with this! Pure beauty I say.

Comment: FWIW, if you really do want (more of a) one-size-fits-all version, you can also use `Hash[*ary.flatten(1)]`, which will preserve array keys and values. It's the recursive `flatten` that is destroying those, which is easy enough to avoid.

Comment: Forgive the dimwit question. What does the * do?

Comment: This answer is not efficient and dangerous. It is also out of date. See my answer.

Comment: @superluminary the `*` explodes (aka unpacks) the array to an argument list of its elements. For example `Hash[1, 2]` returns the hash `{ 1 => 2 }`. That's equivalent to `a = [1, 2]; Hash[*a]`

Comment: For arrays larger than about 65,000, this fails with `stack level too deep (SystemStackError)`.  (Ruby 1.9.3, Ubuntu 14.)

Comment: It seems to me that the pertinent bits of this can be shortened to `Hash[*a1]` and `Hash[a2]` without no change on this particular set of data, and without losing things one might lose with different data; see an answer I recently added for more details.  Even `.flatten(1)` has the potential to lose important stuff here.

Answer (score 99):

The best way is to use [`Array#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h):

```
[ [:apple,1],[:banana,2] ].to_h  #=> {apple: 1, banana: 2}
```

Note that `to_h` also accepts a block:

```
[:apple, :banana].to_h { |fruit| [fruit, "I like #{fruit}s"] } 
  # => {apple: "I like apples", banana: "I like bananas"}
```

**Note**: `to_h` accepts a block in Ruby 2.6.0+; for early rubies you can use my `backports` gem and [`require 'backports/2.6.0/enumerable/to_h'`](http://github.com/marcandre/backports)

`to_h` without a block was introduced in Ruby 2.1.0.

Before Ruby 2.1, one could use the less legible `Hash[]`:

```
array = [ [:apple,1],[:banana,2] ]
Hash[ array ]  #= > {:apple => 1, :banana => 2}
```

Finally, be wary of any solutions using `flatten`, this could create problems with values that are arrays themselves.

Comment: I like the `to_h` method better than the above answers because it expresses the intent of converting ***after*** operating on the array.

Comment: @BSeven Neither `Array#to_h` nor `Enumerable#to_h` is in core ruby 1.9.

Comment: What if I have an array as `[[apple, 1], [banana, 2], [apple, 3], [banana, 4]]` and I want the output as `{"apple" =>[1,3], "banana"=>[2,4]}`?

Comment: @NishantKumar that's a different question.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune I have used something like this

`properties.map{|element| element.split '=' }.to_h` and it gives me some error like this:

`wrong array length at 20 (expected 2, was 3)`

My created array is something like this: 
`[key1 = value1, key2 = value2, ...]`

Can anyone suggest as to what thing is incorrect with my code. Thanks.

Comment: Commenting here is not the way to go. Still, clearly one of you element looks like "a=b=c".

Answer (score 23):

**Update**

[Ruby 2.1.0 is released today](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/12/25/ruby-2-1-0-is-released/). And I comes with `Array#to_h` ([release notes](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_0/NEWS#L34) and [ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h)), which solves the issue of converting an `Array` to a `Hash`.

Ruby docs example:

```
[[:foo, :bar], [1, 2]].to_h    # => {:foo => :bar, 1 => 2}
```

Answer (score 10):

> Edit: Saw the responses posted while I was writing, Hash[a.flatten] seems the way to go.
>   Must have missed that bit in the documentation when I was thinking through the response. Thought the solutions that I've written can be used as alternatives if required.

The second form is simpler:

```
a = [[:apple, 1], [:banana, 2]]
h = a.inject({}) { |r, i| r[i.first] = i.last; r }
```

a = array, h = hash, r = return-value hash (the one we accumulate in), i = item in the array

The neatest way that I can think of doing the first form is something like this:

```
a = [:apple, 1, :banana, 2]
h = {}
a.each_slice(2) { |i| h[i.first] = i.last }
```

Comment: +1 for the `a.inject({})` one-liner that allows for more flexible value assignments.

Comment: It's also possible to drop the `h = {}` from the second example via use of inject, ending up with `a.each_slice(2).inject({}) { |h,i| h[i.first] = i.last; h }`

Comment: You could do `a.each_slice(2).to_h`

Answer (score 7):

## Summary & TL;DR:

This answer hopes to be a comprehensive wrap-up of information from other answers.

The very short version, given the data from the question plus a couple extras:

```
flat_array   = [  apple, 1,   banana, 2  ] # count=4
nested_array = [ [apple, 1], [banana, 2] ] # count=2 of count=2 k,v arrays
incomplete_f = [  apple, 1,   banana     ] # count=3 - missing last value
incomplete_n = [ [apple, 1], [banana   ] ] # count=2 of either k or k,v arrays


# there's one option for flat_array:
h1  = Hash[*flat_array]                     # => {apple=>1, banana=>2}

# two options for nested_array:
h2a = nested_array.to_h # since ruby 2.1.0    => {apple=>1, banana=>2}
h2b = Hash[nested_array]                    # => {apple=>1, banana=>2}

# ok if *only* the last value is missing:
h3  = Hash[incomplete_f.each_slice(2).to_a] # => {apple=>1, banana=>nil}
# always ok for k without v in nested array:
h4  = Hash[incomplete_n] # or .to_h           => {apple=>1, banana=>nil}

# as one might expect:
h1 == h2a # => true
h1 == h2b # => true
h1 == h3  # => false
h3 == h4  # => true
```

Discussion and details follow.

---

## Setup: variables

In order to show the data we'll be using up front, I'll create some variables to represent various possibilities for the data. They fit into the following categories:

#### Based on what was directly in the question, as `a1` and `a2`:

*(Note: I presume that `apple` and `banana` were meant to represent variables. As others have done, I'll be using strings from here on so that input and results can match.)*

```ruby
a1 = [  'apple', 1 ,  'banana', 2  ] # flat input
a2 = [ ['apple', 1], ['banana', 2] ] # key/value paired input
```

#### Multi-value keys and/or values, as `a3`:

In some other answers, another possibility was presented (which I expand on here) – keys and/or values may be arrays on their own:

```ruby
a3 = [ [ 'apple',                   1   ],
       [ 'banana',                  2   ],
       [ ['orange','seedless'],     3   ],
       [ 'pear',                 [4, 5] ],
     ]
```

#### Unbalanced array, as `a4`:

For good measure, I thought I'd add one for a case where we might have an incomplete input:

```ruby
a4 = [ [ 'apple',                   1],
       [ 'banana',                  2],
       [ ['orange','seedless'],     3],
       [ 'durian'                    ], # a spiky fruit pricks us: no value!
     ]
```

---

## Now, to work:

### Starting with an initially-flat array, `a1`:

Some have suggested using [`#to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-to_h) (which showed up in Ruby 2.1.0, and can be [backported](https://github.com/marcandre/backports) to earlier versions). For an initially-flat array, this doesn't work:

```ruby
a1.to_h   # => TypeError: wrong element type String at 0 (expected array)
```

Using [`Hash::[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) combined with the [splat operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion) does:

```ruby
Hash[*a1] # => {"apple"=>1, "banana"=>2}
```

So that's the solution for the simple case represented by `a1`.

### With an array of key/value pair arrays, `a2`:

With an array of `[key,value]` type arrays, there are two ways to go.

First, `Hash::[]` still works (as it did with `*a1`):

```ruby
Hash[a2] # => {"apple"=>1, "banana"=>2}
```

And then also `#to_h` works now:

```ruby
a2.to_h  # => {"apple"=>1, "banana"=>2}
```

So, two easy answers for the simple nested array case.

#### This remains true even with sub-arrays as keys or values, as with `a3`:

```ruby
Hash[a3] # => {"apple"=>1, "banana"=>2, ["orange", "seedless"]=>3, "pear"=>[4, 5]} 
a3.to_h  # => {"apple"=>1, "banana"=>2, ["orange", "seedless"]=>3, "pear"=>[4, 5]}
```

### But durians have spikes (anomalous structures give problems):

If we've gotten input data that's not balanced, we'll run into problems with `#to_h`:

```ruby
a4.to_h  # => ArgumentError: wrong array length at 3 (expected 2, was 1)
```

But `Hash::[]` still works, just setting `nil` as the value for `durian` (and any other array element in a4 that's just a 1-value array):

```ruby
Hash[a4] # => {"apple"=>1, "banana"=>2, ["orange", "seedless"]=>3, "durian"=>nil}
```

#### Flattening - using new variables `a5` and `a6`

A few other answers mentioned [`flatten`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-flatten), with or without a `1` argument, so let's create some new variables:

```ruby
a5 = a4.flatten
# => ["apple", 1, "banana", 2,  "orange", "seedless" , 3, "durian"] 
a6 = a4.flatten(1)
# => ["apple", 1, "banana", 2, ["orange", "seedless"], 3, "durian"]
```

I chose to use `a4` as the base data because of the balance problem we had, which showed up with `a4.to_h`.  I figure calling `flatten` might be one approach someone might use to try to solve that, which might look like the following.

#### `flatten` without arguments (`a5`):

```ruby
Hash[*a5]       # => {"apple"=>1, "banana"=>2, "orange"=>"seedless", 3=>"durian"}
# (This is the same as calling `Hash[*a4.flatten]`.)
```

At a naïve glance, this appears to work – but it got us off on the wrong foot with the seedless oranges, thus also making `3` a *key* and `durian` a *value*.

And this, as with `a1`, just doesn't work:

```ruby
a5.to_h # => TypeError: wrong element type String at 0 (expected array)
```

So `a4.flatten` isn't useful to us, we'd just want to use `Hash[a4]`

#### The `flatten(1)` case (`a6`):

But what about only partially flattening?  It's worth noting that calling `Hash::[]` using `splat` on the partially-flattened array (`a6`) is *not* the same as calling `Hash[a4]`:

```ruby
Hash[*a6] # => ArgumentError: odd number of arguments for Hash
```

#### Pre-flattened array, still nested (alternate way of getting `a6`):

But what if this was how we'd gotten the array in the first place?
 (That is, comparably to `a1`, it was our input data - just this time some of the data can be arrays or other objects.)  We've seen that `Hash[*a6]` doesn't work, but what if we still wanted to get the behavior where the *last element* (important! see below) acted as a key for a `nil` value?

In such a situation, there's still a way to do this, using [`Enumerable#each_slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) to get ourselves back to key/value *pairs* as elements in the outer array:

```ruby
a7 = a6.each_slice(2).to_a
# => [["apple", 1], ["banana", 2], [["orange", "seedless"], 3], ["durian"]]
```

Note that this ends up getting us a new array that isn't "[identical](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-equal-3F)" to `a4`, but does have the [same values](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-3D-3D):

```ruby
a4.equal?(a7) # => false
a4 == a7      # => true
```

And thus we can again use `Hash::[]`:

```ruby
Hash[a7] # => {"apple"=>1, "banana"=>2, ["orange", "seedless"]=>3, "durian"=>nil}
# or Hash[a6.each_slice(2).to_a]
```

#### But there's a problem!

It's important to note that the `each_slice(2)` solution only gets things back to sanity if the ***last*** key was the one missing a value.  If we later added an extra key/value pair:

```ruby
a4_plus = a4.dup # just to have a new-but-related variable name
a4_plus.push(['lychee', 4])
# => [["apple",                1],
#     ["banana",               2],
#     [["orange", "seedless"], 3], # multi-value key
#     ["durian"],              # missing value
#     ["lychee", 4]]           # new well-formed item

a6_plus = a4_plus.flatten(1)
# => ["apple", 1, "banana", 2, ["orange", "seedless"], 3, "durian", "lychee", 4]

a7_plus = a6_plus.each_slice(2).to_a
# => [["apple",                1],
#     ["banana",               2],
#     [["orange", "seedless"], 3], # so far so good
#     ["durian",               "lychee"], # oops! key became value!
#     [4]]                     # and we still have a key without a value

a4_plus == a7_plus # => false, unlike a4 == a7
```

And the two hashes we'd get from this are different in important ways:

```ruby
ap Hash[a4_plus] # prints:
{
                     "apple" => 1,
                    "banana" => 2,
    [ "orange", "seedless" ] => 3,
                    "durian" => nil, # correct
                    "lychee" => 4    # correct
}

ap Hash[a7_plus] # prints:
{
                     "apple" => 1,
                    "banana" => 2,
    [ "orange", "seedless" ] => 3,
                    "durian" => "lychee", # incorrect
                           4 => nil       # incorrect
}
```

*(Note: I'm using [`awesome_print`](https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print)'s `ap` just to make it easier to show the structure here; there's no conceptual requirement for this.)*

So the `each_slice` solution to an unbalanced flat input only works if the unbalanced bit is at the very end.

---

## Take-aways:

1. Whenever possible, set up input to these things as `[key, value]` pairs (a sub-array for each item in the outer array).
2. When you can indeed do that, either `#to_h` or `Hash::[]` will both work.
3. If you're unable to, `Hash::[]` combined with the splat (`*`) will work, *so long as inputs are balanced*.
4. With an *unbalanced* and *flat* array as input, the only way this will work at all reasonably is if the ***last*** `value` item is the only one that's missing.

---

*Side-note: I'm posting this answer because I feel there's value to be added – some of the existing answers have incorrect information, and none (that I read) gave as complete an answer as I'm endeavoring to do here.  I hope that it's helpful.  I nevertheless give thanks to those who came before me, several of whom provided inspiration for portions of this answer.*

Answer (score 5):

You can also simply convert a 2D array into hash using:

```
1.9.3p362 :005 > a= [[1,2],[3,4]]

 => [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

1.9.3p362 :006 > h = Hash[a]

 => {1=>2, 3=>4}
```

Answer (score 3):

Appending to the answer but using anonymous arrays and annotating:

```
Hash[*("a,b,c,d".split(',').zip([1,2,3,4]).flatten)]
```

Taking that answer apart, starting from the inside:

- `"a,b,c,d"` is actually a string.
- `split` on commas into an array.
- `zip` that together with the following array.
- `[1,2,3,4]` is an actual array.

The intermediate result is:

```
[[a,1],[b,2],[c,3],[d,4]]
```

flatten then transforms that to:

```
["a",1,"b",2,"c",3,"d",4]
```

and then:

`*["a",1,"b",2,"c",3,"d",4]` unrolls that into
`"a",1,"b",2,"c",3,"d",4`

which we can use as the arguments to the `Hash[]` method:

```
Hash[*("a,b,c,d".split(',').zip([1,2,3,4]).flatten)]
```

which yields:

```
{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4}
```

Comment: This also works without the splat (`*`) and flatten: `Hash[("a,b,c,d".split(',').zip([1,2,3,4]))]` => `{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4}`.  More detail in an answer I added.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best way, but this works:

```
a = ["apple", 1, "banana", 2]
m1 = {}
for x in (a.length / 2).times
  m1[a[x*2]] = a[x*2 + 1]
end

b = [["apple", 1], ["banana", 2]]
m2 = {}
for x,y in b
  m2[x] = y
end
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have array that looks like this -

```
data = [["foo",1,2,3,4],["bar",1,2],["foobar",1,"*",3,5,:foo]]
```

and you want the first elements of each array to become the keys for the hash and the rest of the elements becoming value arrays, then you can do something like this -

```
data_hash = Hash[data.map { |key| [key.shift, key] }]

#=>{"foo"=>[1, 2, 3, 4], "bar"=>[1, 2], "foobar"=>[1, "*", 3, 5, :foo]}
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance and memory allocation concerns please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856407/rails-mapping-array-of-hashes-onto-single-hash/68745019#answer-68745019) to [Rails mapping array of hashes onto single hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856407/rails-mapping-array-of-hashes-onto-single-hash/68745019) where I bench-marked several solutions.

`reduce` / `inject` can be the fastest or the slowest solution depending on which method you use it which.

Answer (score -1):

If the numeric values are seq indexes, then we could have simpler ways... 
Here's my code submission, My Ruby is a bit rusty

```
   input = ["cat", 1, "dog", 2, "wombat", 3]
   hash = Hash.new
   input.each_with_index {|item, index|
     if (index%2 == 0) hash[item] = input[index+1]
   }
   hash   #=> {"cat"=>1, "wombat"=>3, "dog"=>2}
```