# Rails rendering JSON --> Square Brakets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rendering

i render some object using json:

```
def index
  if user_signed_in?
   @todos = current_user.todos.find_all()
   render :json => @todos
  else
    return nil
  end
end
```

it actually does that, but there's a problem. I get square brakets [ ] arround the json output and some plugins or json viewers cannot read it because of them. Here some sample output:

```
[{"todo":{"name":"Test todo","created_at":"2010-11-24T07:40:07Z","updated_at":"2010-11-24T07:40:07Z","done":0,"id":1,"user_id":1}},{"todo":{"name":"Ali Test","created_at":"2010-11-24T07:40:30Z","updated_at":"2010-11-24T07:40:30Z","done":0,"id":2,"user_id":1}}]
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: find_all returns an array, so this is precisely the JSON you should expect.

Comment: ahhh okay. so how can i render all entries with actually have those array brakets?

Comment: `@todos.each{|t| t.to_json}` will give you an array of json objects that you could render separately.

Comment: `@todos.each{|t| t.to_json}` works perfectly in rails 4.2.5 in a jbuilder view. Thanks aceofspades!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
render :json => @todos.to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the JSON output you are expecting you need to render a Hash and not an Array. 
 Here is an in-depth post on converting:

[What is the best way to convert an array to a hash in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-an-array-to-a-hash-in-ruby)

Quick summary with OP syntax:

```
 render :json => Hash[*@todos.flatten]
```

or for an asymmetrical array

```
render :json => Hash[@todos.map {|key, value| [key, value]}]
```

In some cases though this adds extra nulls that you don't want and you may have to break your array down and flatten it or simply use Hash[ instead of [ whenever possible.