# RoR display count of group by on html table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

i am trying to run a activerecord statement like this

```
@items=History.count(:group => "DATE(timelogin)")
```

on my view i am, trying to show my records in html table like this

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
   <% @item.each do |key,val| %>
      <tr>
         <td> <% key %></td>
         <td> <% val %></td>
      </tr>
   <% end %>
</table>
```

i tried something else and while searching over i came up with following link
[What is the best way to convert an array to a hash in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-an-array-to-a-hash-in-ruby) and i replaced my view code as it is shown in the link.

but it does nothing. i later added `=` like this

```
<%= @item.each do |key,val| %>
```

it showed whole result in once and rendered empty table.

the result that is rendered on webpage and in rails console is like:

```
{"2014-01-08"=>1, "2013-12-31"=>2, "2013-12-30"=>2, "2013-12-26"=>5, "2013-12-24"=>1,
"2013-12-23"=>1, "2013-12-20"=>2, "2013-12-18"=>2, "2013-12-17"=>2, "2013-12-04"=>1, 
"2013-12-03"=>5, "2013-12-02"=>1, "2013-11-28"=>7, "2013-11-20"=>1, "2013-11-19"=>1, 
"2013-11-18"=>1, "2013-11-12"=>1, "2013-11-06"=>1, "2013-10-29"=>2, "2013-10-25"=>1, 
"2013-10-23"=>1, "2013-10-15"=>1, "2013-10-14"=>3, "2013-10-10"=>2}
```

Please let me know what wrong i have done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing `=`.  Use it to output.  Also, you are using `@item` in the view, but assigning the values to `@items` in the code.  There is a missing `s`.

```
<% @items.each do |key,val| %>
   <tr>
      <td> <%= key %></td>
      <td> <%= val %></td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
 <% @item.each do |key,val| %>
  <tr>
     <td> <%= key %></td>
     <td> <%= val %></td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
</table>
```