# ruby convert array of delimited strings into hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, parsing, hash

I have an array

```
["bob:12 elm st", "sally:100 digital ave", "tom:2324 elmhurst st"]
```

which I need to convert to

```
{"bob" => "12 elm st", "sally" => "100 digital ave", "tom" => "2324 elmhurst st"}.
```

I know I can do

```
array.each do |e|
  k = e.split(":").first
  v = e.split(":").last
  hash[k] = v
end
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to convert an array to a hash in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-an-array-to-a-hash-in-ruby)

Answer (score 7):

`Hash[]` constructs a hash from array.

```
Hash[array.map {|el| el.split ':'}]
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe ruby 2.1 has a .to_h method.

Therefor,

```
array.map { |i| i.split ':' }.to_h
```

will work.