# Merge Complex Hash of Arrays of Hashes Simultaneously on Multiple Levels

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, merge

I realize there are many questions of varying degrees of similarity to this one.  I've searched at length (using: *[ruby] merge array of hashes on key*) for them and I have attempted bits and pieces of each answer to try to solve this on my own.  Before coming to StackOverflow, I even shared my question with my colleagues who have been equally stumped.  This seems to be a unique question or we're all just staring too closely at it to see an otherwise obvious answer.

**Essential Requirements**

1. The solution must work with the Ruby 1.8.7 standard library (no gems).  Please feel free to additionally illustrate solutions for other versions of Ruby, but doing so will not automatically make one answer better than another.
2. The structure of the input data cannot be changed by its provider; the entire data structure is delivered as-is.  If the data needs to be temporarily rearranged to provide the most efficient answer, that's perfectly fine as long as the output matches the required sample below.  In addition, the solution can make no assumptions about the position of the sorting keys within the Hashes.
3. The source variable cannot be altered in any way; it is immutable at run-time (this is checked), so the result must be provided to a new variable.
4. The sample data below is fiction but the problem is real.  There are other levels of Arrays-of-Hashes that must also be merged on other keys in the same way; so, the very best answer can be generically applied to arbitrary levels of the data structure.
5. The best solution will be easy to read, maintain, and apply to arbitrary -- though similar -- data structures.  It needn't be a one-liner but if you can meet all the requirements in a single line of Ruby code, kudos to you.

**Sample Data**

If we think of the Apache Tomcat server.xml file as a Ruby data structure rather than XML, it can provide a very good analog for this problem.  Assume further that the default configuration is merged upstream -- before being delivered to you -- with data that you must consolidate before some later operation consumes the resulting data structure.  The source data will look very much like this:

```
source = {
  :Server => {
    :'attribute.port'     => 8005,
    :'attribute.shutdown' => 'SHUTDOWN',
    :Listener             => [
      { :'attribute.className'  => 'org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener' },
      { :'attribute.className'  => 'org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener',
        :'attribute.SSLEngine'  => 'off'},
      { :'attribute.className'  => 'org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener' },
      { :'attribute.className'  => 'org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener' },
      { :'attribute.className'  => 'org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener',
        :'attribute.SSLEngine'  => 'on'}
    ],
    :Service              => [
      { :'attribute.name' => 'Catalina',
        :Connector        => [
          { :'attribute.port'     => 8080,
            :'attribute.protocol' => 'HTTP/1.1'},
          { :'attribute.port'     => 8009,
            :'attribute.protocol' => 'AJP/1.3'}
        ],
        :Engine           => {
          :'attribute.name'         => 'Catalina',
          :'attribute.defaultHost'  => 'localhost',
          :Realm                    => {
            :'attribute.className'  => 'org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm',
            :Realm                  => [
              { :'attribute.className'    => 'org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm',
                :'attribute.resourceName' => 'UserDatabase'}
            ]
          },
          :Host                     => [
            { :'attribute.name'     => 'localhost',
              :'attribute.appBase'  => 'webapps',
              :Valve                => [
                { :'attribute.className'  => 'org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve',
                  :'attribute.directory'  => 'logs'}
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      { :'attribute.name' => 'Catalina',
        :Connector        => [
          { :'attribute.port'         => 8080,
            :'attribute.protocol'     => 'HTTP/1.1',
            :'attribute.secure'       => true,
            :'attribute.scheme'       => 'https',
            :'attribute.proxyPort'    => 443}
        ]
      },
      { :'attribute.name' => 'JSVCBridge',
        :Connector        => [
          { :'attribute.port'         => 8010,
            :'attribute.protocol'     => 'HTTP/2'}
        ]
      },
      { :'attribute.name' => 'Catalina',
        :Engine           => {
          :Host => [
            { :'attribute.name'     => 'localhost',
              :Valve                => [
                { :'attribute.className'                => 'org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve',
                  :'attribute.internalProxies'          => '*',
                  :'attribute.remoteIpHeader'           => 'X-Forwarded-For',
                  :'attribute.protocolHeader'           => 'X-Forwarded-Proto',
                  :'attribute.protocolHeaderHttpsValue' => 'https'}
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The challenge is to produce this result from it:

```
result = {
  :Server => {
    :'attribute.port'     => 8005,
    :'attribute.shutdown' => 'SHUTDOWN',
    :Listener             => [
      { :'attribute.className'  => 'org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener' },
      { :'attribute.className'  => 'org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener',
        :'attribute.SSLEngine'  => 'on'},
      { :'attribute.className'  => 'org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener' },
      { :'attribute.className'  => 'org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener' },
    ],
    :Service              => [
      { :'attribute.name' => 'Catalina',
        :Connector        => [
          { :'attribute.port'         => 8080,
            :'attribute.protocol'     => 'HTTP/1.1',
            :'attribute.secure'       => true,
            :'attribute.scheme'       => 'https',
            :'attribute.proxyPort'    => 443},
          { :'attribute.port'     => 8009,
            :'attribute.protocol' => 'AJP/1.3'}
        ],
        :Engine           => {
          :'attribute.name'         => 'Catalina',
          :'attribute.defaultHost'  => 'localhost',
          :Realm                    => {
            :'attribute.className'  => 'org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm',
            :Realm                  => [
              { :'attribute.className'    => 'org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm',
                :'attribute.resourceName' => 'UserDatabase'}
            ]
          },
          :Host                     => [
            { :'attribute.name'     => 'localhost',
              :'attribute.appBase'  => 'webapps',
              :Valve                => [
                { :'attribute.className'  => 'org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve',
                  :'attribute.directory'  => 'logs'},
                { :'attribute.className'                => 'org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve',
                  :'attribute.internalProxies'          => '*',
                  :'attribute.remoteIpHeader'           => 'X-Forwarded-For',
                  :'attribute.protocolHeader'           => 'X-Forwarded-Proto',
                  :'attribute.protocolHeaderHttpsValue' => 'https'}
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      { :'attribute.name' => 'JSVCBridge',
        :Connector        => [
          { :'attribute.port'         => 8010,
            :'attribute.protocol'     => 'HTTP/2'}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**The Question**

We need `source` to become `result`.  To get there, `:Listener` gets merged by `attribute.className`; `:Service` gets merged by `attribute.name`; the resulting Arrays of `:Connector` get merged by `attribute.port`; and such.  The identification of the location of the Arrays-of-Hashes within the data structure and the key which each is to be merged on should be easily provided to the solution.

The real essence of this question is finding that generic solution that can apply to multiple arbitrary levels of a complex data structure like this, merge Arrays-of-Hashes by a supplied key, and produce the merged result after the set of location and key pairs is provided.

Thank you all very much for your time and interest in this question.

Comment: what rule determines the changes in :Listener? is it simply that in an array of hashes, if keys are duplicated, that latest instance of the key is the only one left standing? if so why does "attribute.className sill appear twice in the result?

Comment: For this question, all Arrays-of-Hashes must be merged on the key such that values in later Hashes in the Array override values in earlier Hashes.  The `:Listener` Array-of-Hashes merges on `attribute.className`, so `attribute.SSLEngine` is `on` for `org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener` in the result.  The `attribute.className` value differs between the two surviving elements of `:Listeners`; only `org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener` needed to be merged.

Comment: could you add in an example of one of the more complex structures you might apply the method to?

Comment: @ian I've expanded the data samples to add more `:Listener` elements and further illustrate additional complexity and expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more elegant ways of condensing this code but I finally developed an answer to this very challenging question.  While Wand Maker's answer came close, it was based on the untenable assumption that the order of the keys in the Hashes would be predictable and stable.  As this is a Ruby 1.8.7 problem and because the data provider makes no such guarantee, I had to take a different path; we had to inform the merge engine which key to use for each Array-of-Hashes.

My (non-optimized) solution required three functions and an external Hash that defines the necessary merge keys:

1. `deepMergeHash` walks through a hash, deeply scanning for Arrays
2. `deepMergeArrayOfHashes` performs the desired merge against an Array-of-Hashes
3. `subMergeHelper` recursively assists `deepMergeArrayOfHashes`

The trick was to not only treat the Hash recursively, but to always be aware of the "present" location within the Hash so that the necessary merge key could be known.  Having established a way to determine that location, defining, finding, and using the merge keys became trivial.

**The Solution**

```
def subMergeHelper(lhs, rhs, mergeKeys, crumbTrail)
  lhs.merge(rhs){|subKey, subLHS, subRHS|
    mergeTrail = crumbTrail + ':' + subKey.to_s
    case subLHS
    when Array
      deepMergeArrayOfHashes(subLHS + subRHS, mergeKeys, mergeTrail)
    when Hash
      subMergeHelper(subLHS, subRHS, mergeKeys, mergeTrail)
    else
      subRHS
    end
  }
end

def deepMergeArrayOfHashes(arrayOfHashes, mergeKeys, crumbTrail)
  mergedArray = arrayOfHashes
  if arrayOfHashes.all? {|e| e.class == Hash}
    if mergeKeys.has_key?(crumbTrail)
      mergeKey = mergeKeys[crumbTrail]
      mergedArray = arrayOfHashes.group_by{|evalHash| evalHash[mergeKey.to_sym]}.map{|groupID, groupArrayOfHashes|
        groupArrayOfHashes.reduce({}){|memoHash, evalHash|
          memoHash.merge(evalHash){|hashKey, lhs, rhs|
            deepTrail = crumbTrail + ':' + hashKey.to_s
            case lhs
            when Array
              deepMergeArrayOfHashes(lhs + rhs, mergeKeys, deepTrail)
            when Hash
              subMergeHelper(lhs, rhs, mergeKeys, deepTrail)
            else
              rhs
            end
          }
        }
      }
    else
      $stderr.puts "[WARNING] deepMergeArrayOfHashes:  received an Array of Hashes without merge key at #{crumbTrail}."
    end
  else
    $stderr.puts "[WARNING] deepMergeArrayOfHashes:  received an Array containing non-Hashes at #{crumbTrail}?"
  end
  return mergedArray
end

def deepMergeHash(hashConfig, mergeKeys, crumbTrail = '')
  return hashConfig unless Hash == hashConfig.class
  mergedConfig = {}
  hashConfig.each{|nodeKey, nodeValue|
    nodeCrumb = nodeKey.to_s
    testTrail = crumbTrail + ':' + nodeCrumb
    case nodeValue
    when Hash
      mergedConfig[nodeKey] = deepMergeHash(nodeValue, mergeKeys, testTrail)
    when Array
      mergedConfig[nodeKey] = deepMergeArrayOfHashes(nodeValue, mergeKeys, testTrail)
    else
      mergedConfig[nodeKey] = nodeValue
    end
  }
  return mergedConfig
end
```

**Example Use**

Using the data in the question, we can now:

```
mergeKeys = {
  ':Server:Listener'                    => 'attribute.className',
  ':Server:Service'                     => 'attribute.name',
  ':Server:Service:Connector'           => 'attribute.port',
  ':Server:Service:Engine:Host'         => 'attribute.name',
  ':Server:Service:Engine:Host:Valve'   => 'attribute.className',
  ':Server:Service:Engine:Realm:Realm'  => 'attribute.className'
}

mergedConfig = deepMergeHash(source, mergeKeys)
```

I can't seem to perform a successful equality test like `(result == mergedConfig)`, but a visual inspection of `mergedConfig` shows that it is identical to `result` except that the order of some keys changes.  I suspect that's a side-effect of using Ruby 1.8.x and is acceptable for this question.

Happy coding, everyone and thank you so much for your interest in this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on assumption that you are merging hashes based on value of first key in the given array of hashes is given below:

```
def merge_ary(ary_hash)
  # Lets not process something that is not array of hash
  return ary_hash if not ary_hash.all? {|h| h.class == Hash }

  # If array of hash, lets group them by value of first key
  # Then, reduce the resultant group of hashes by merging them.
  c = ary_hash.group_by {|h| h.values.first}.map do |k,v| 
    v_reduced = v.reduce({}) do |memo_hash, h|
      memo_hash.merge(h) do |k, v1, v2|
        v1.class == Array ? merge_ary(v1 + v2) : v2
      end
    end
    [k, v_reduced]
  end
  return Hash[c].values
end

def merge_hash(hash)
  t = hash.map do |k,v|
    new_v = v
    if v.class == Hash
      new_v = merge_hash(v)
    elsif v.class == Array
      new_v = merge_ary(v)
    end
    [k,new_v]
  end
  return Hash[t]
end

# Test the output
merge_hash(source) == result
#=> true
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach that I'll toy with.  It's not viable as-is unfortunately because we are dealing with Hashes containing Arrays of Hashes.  The order of keys cannot be guaranteed.  I wrote the source and result data by hand for this question, so the fact that the desired key is always first in my samples is only because I wanted the keys to be readily seen by readers when reviewing the data (since I called them out in the question).  In this light, `merge_ary` needs to be informed which key to merge on and thus, we need a way to provide those key names for each Array.

Comment: Unless I've messed up my Ruby environment, it also seems that `to_h` may not be available in the Ruby 1.8.7 standard library where you're using it:  `NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_h'`

Comment: to_h is not there in 1.8.7,   have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20831486/794242 for an alternative

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation but we unfortunately can't use Ruby > 1.8.7 nor can we use gems for this particular problem.

Comment: @seWilliam  I have updated the answer not to use `to_h`, but it does not take care of your recent updates to question - the test fails with your current question's data