# Combine first elements of multidimensional array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have an array of **product IDs** and **Quantities**, like this:

```
records = [[1, 10], [1, 30], [4, 10], [4, 100], [5, 45]]
```

What's the easiest/most efficient way in **Ruby** to achieve a hash of the combined products and quantities, like this?

```
products_needed = [{id: 1, count:40}, {id: 4, count: 110}, {id:5, count:45}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to convert an array to a hash in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-an-array-to-a-hash-in-ruby)

Comment: Is there a particular reason for wanting an array of hashes rather than one hash? If you did the latter you would do without the labels but it would be fast searchable by ID and take up less memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
records.group_by(&:first).map do |id, records_for_id|
  {
     id: id,
     count: records_for_id.sum(&:last)
  }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're in Ruby 2.4+, you can use [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) followed by [`transform_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values):

```
records.group_by(&:first) # => {1=>[[1, 10], [1, 30]], 4=>[[4, 10], [4, 100]], 5=>[[5, 45]]}

records.group_by(&:first).transform_values do |values|
  values.sum(&:last)
end # => {1=>40, 4=>110, 5=>45}
```

Comment: `transform_values` requires Ruby 2.4+ (or Rails)

Answer (score 1):

```
records
.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|(k, v), h| h.merge!(k => v){|_, v1, v2| v1 + v2}}
# => {1=>40, 4=>110, 5=>45}

records
.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|(k, v), h| h.merge!(k => v){|_, v1, v2| v1 + v2}}
.map{|k, v| {id: k, count: v}}
# => [{:id=>1, :count=>40}, {:id=>4, :count=>110}, {:id=>5, :count=>45}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You *don't* have an array of product IDs and Quantities. You have an array of arrays of integers. The easiest way to deal with this array of arrays of integers is to not have an array of arrays of integers but an `Order`:

```
class Product
  def to_s; 'Some Product' end
  alias_method :inspect, :to_s
end

class LineItem
  attr_reader :product, :count

  def initialize(product, count)
    self.product, self.count = product, count
  end

  def to_s; "#{count} x #{product}" end
  alias_method :inspect, :to_s

  private

  attr_writer :product, :count
end

class Order
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(*line_items)
    self.line_items = line_items
  end

  def each(&blk) line_items.each(&blk) end

  def items
    group_by(&:product).map {|product, line_items| LineItem.new(product, line_items.sum(&:count)) }
  end

  def to_s; line_items.map(&:to_s).join(', ') end
  alias_method :inspect, :to_s

  private

  attr_accessor :line_items
end
```

Now, assuming that you receive your data in the form of an `Order`, instead of an array of arrays of integers, like this:

```
product1 = Product.new
product4 = Product.new
product5 = Product.new

order = Order.new(
  LineItem.new(product1, 10), 
  LineItem.new(product1, 30), 
  LineItem.new(product4, 10), 
  LineItem.new(product4, 100), 
  LineItem.new(product5, 45)
)
```

All you need to do is:

```
order.items
#=> [40 x Some Product, 110 x Some Product, 45 x Some Product]
```

The bottom line is: Ruby is an object-oriented language, not an array-of-arrays-of-integers-oriented language, if you use rich objects instead of arrays of arrays of integers, your problem will become much simpler.

Note: I used order processing as an example. If your problem domain is warehouse management or something else, there will be a similar solution.

Comment: Why would you assume he/she had any choice about the source data? I would assume this array of arrays came from something like a text file parser.

Comment: Then the OP can convert it to a proper object model at the place where it enters the system.

Comment: Yes but do you genuinely think your answer is a wiser choice than the simple accepted answer? This is a question of philosophy. Mine is that no philosophy suits all problem domains. If this part of the code is business-logic rich and likely to be revisited a lot and keep growing in complexity then a purist OOP approach becomes justified.